# Update for metadata?.downloadURL().absoluteString that returns a String

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to update metadata?.downloadURL().absoluteString for extracting an image URL, downloading that URL as a string, and then uploading the image URL to my Firebase database. The code in the new Firebase documentation returns void, and I don't know how to make it return a String for the image URL.

```
storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: {(metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                //*********** Need to fix this **************
                let photoUrl = storageRef.downloadURL(completion: {imageData, error in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("Failed to download url:", error!)
                        return
                    } else {
                        //Do something with url
                    }
                    
                })
                //self.sendDatatoDatabase(photoUrl: photoUrl)
                //*******************************************
            })
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Note that  storageRef.downloadURL completion handler returns an url and error, therefore naming the url as imageData is misleading

Comment: `storageRef.downloadURL { url, error in` `if let error = error {` `print("Failed to download url:", error)` `return` `} else {` `// use your url here` `}` `}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `metadata.downloadURL` no longer exists (and hasn't existed in SDKs released since May 2018). To get the download URL you now have to call `downloadURL()` on the storage reference and then use the URL in the callback.

So the place to put your own code that needs the download URL is right where it now says `//Do something with url` in the code you got from the documentation. If you want to pass that URL to your `` method, that'd looks something like:

```
storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: {(metadata, error) in
    if error != nil {
        ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
    //*********** Need to fix this **************
    let photoUrl = storageRef.downloadURL(completion: {url, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("Failed to download url:", error!)
            return
        } else {
            self.sendDatatoDatabase(photoUrl: url)
        }
        
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks much appreciated!

Comment: I don't have enough reputation yet but I've clicked the check mark!